# fabric can NOT call the remote script with nohup

Tags: python, fabric, nohup

In remote server, I have a script test.sh like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm here!"
nohup sleep 100&
```

From local, I run 'fab runtest' to call the remote test.sh.

```
def runtest():
    run('xxxx/test.sh')
```

I can get the output "I'm here!", but I can Not find the sleep process in remote sever.
What did I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to run the nohup inside the script in remote machine?

I checked the answer here and [Fabric FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/faq.html), also get the hints from [fabric appears to start apache2 but doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379484/fabric-appears-to-start-apache2-but-doesnt/) and it works for me to combine them together

You can keep your `test.sh` without changes, and add `pty=False` with related shell redirection.

```py
from fabric.api import *
def runtest():
    run("nohup /tmp/test.sh >& /dev/null < /dev/null &",pty=False)
```

At least, it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Fabric FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang) you can no longer effectively do this. Instead you should use tmux, screen, dtach or even better use the [python daemon package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon):

```
import daemon

from spam import do_main_program

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    do_main_program()
```

Comment: This answer is outdated. The OP posts a link to the 1.6 doc version, as the answer posts a link to the 1.2.2 doc version.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this problem and found that you can use `nohup` in a command, but not in the script itself.

For example, `run('nohup xxxx/test.sh')` works.

Comment: good hints from you, and it is possible to run nohup inside scripts, see my answer.