# How to start a background process with nohup using Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Through [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/), I am trying to start a celerycam process using the below `nohup` command. Unfortunately, nothing is happening. Manually using the same command, I could start the process but not through Fabric. Any advice on how can I solve this?

```
def start_celerycam():
    '''Start celerycam daemon'''
    with cd(env.project_dir):
        virtualenv('nohup bash -c "python manage.py celerycam --logfile=%scelerycam.log --pidfile=%scelerycam.pid &> %scelerycam.nohup &> %scelerycam.err" &' % (env.celery_log_dir,env.celery_log_dir,env.celery_log_dir,env.celery_log_dir))
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm using Erich Heine's suggestion to use 'dtach' and it's working pretty well for me:

```
def runbg(cmd, sockname="dtach"):
    return run('dtach -n `mktemp -u /tmp/%s.XXXX` %s' % (sockname, cmd))
```

This was found [here](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang).

Comment: I tried a bunch of different ways of doing this.  This was the one that finally worked.

Comment: I tried this, it works! But when I add nohup in 'cmd', still not working, so I just removed nohup and '&'.

Comment: How can I see the logs of the detached execution. Can it be configured?Or will there be a specific location where I can look for?

Answer (score 21):

As I have experimented, the solution is a combination of two factors:

- run process as a **daemon**: nohup ./command &> /dev/null &
- use **pty=False** for fabric run

So, your function should look like this:

```
def background_run(command):
    command = 'nohup %s &> /dev/null &' % command
    run(command, pty=False)
```

And you can launch it with:

```
execute(background_run, your_command)
```

Comment: `mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for devic`

Answer (score 8):

This is an instance of [this issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/395).  Background processes will be killed when the command ends.  Unfortunately on CentOS 6 doesn't support pty-less sudo commands.

The final entry in the issue mentions using `sudo('set -m; service servicename start')`.  This turns on Job Control and therefore background processes are put in their own process group.  As a result they are not terminated when the command ends.

For even more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679178/why-does-ssh-wait-for-my-subshells-without-t-and-kill-them-with-t/14866774#14866774) link.

Comment: +1: Thanks! The `pty=false` suggestion wasn't working for me on RHEL (because sudo required TTY), but prefixing `set -m;` worked great! Could we get more information on what the ramifications of `set -m;` are, though? What exactly is that doing / how is this solution working? Is there something I should be wary of? Is there some cleanup I should perform later on?

Comment: For me, both `run("nohup %s >& /dev/null < dev/null &" % cmd, pty=False)` as well as `run ("set -m; nohup %s &" % cmd)` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

you just need to run

```
run("(nohup yourcommand >& /dev/null < /dev/null &) && sleep 1")
```

Comment: Wow,  how did you find this? A slightly simpler version would also be
    `(nohup yourcommand &> /dev/null < /dev/null &) && /bin/true`

Answer (score 4):

DTACH is the way to go. It's a software you need to install like a lite version of screen.
This is a better version of the "dtach"-method found above, it will install dtach if necessary. It's to be found [here](http://prschmid.blogspot.de/2014/02/running-background-tasks-with-fabric.html) where you can also learn how to get the output of the process which is running in the background:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import sudo
from fabric.contrib.files import exists


def run_bg(cmd, before=None, sockname="dtach", use_sudo=False):
    """Run a command in the background using dtach

    :param cmd: The command to run
    :param output_file: The file to send all of the output to.
    :param before: The command to run before the dtach. E.g. exporting
                   environment variable
    :param sockname: The socket name to use for the temp file
    :param use_sudo: Whether or not to use sudo
    """
    if not exists("/usr/bin/dtach"):
        sudo("apt-get install dtach")
    if before:
        cmd = "{}; dtach -n `mktemp -u /tmp/{}.XXXX` {}".format(
            before, sockname, cmd)
    else:
        cmd = "dtach -n `mktemp -u /tmp/{}.XXXX` {}".format(sockname, cmd)
    if use_sudo:
        return sudo(cmd)
    else:
        return run(cmd)
```

May this help you, like it helped me to run omxplayer via fabric on a remote rasberry pi!

Comment: Did you actually every get it to pump the results to an output_file? Your code doesn't seem to actually use that parameter. I'm trying to understand how I can log events?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a way to get the output logs. Did you guys managed to find any solution to store the logs to an output file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
run('nohup /home/ubuntu/spider/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/spider/Desktop/baidu_index/baidu_index.py > /home/ubuntu/spider/Desktop/baidu_index/baidu_index.py.log 2>&1 &', pty=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

`nohup` did not work for me and I did not have `tmux` or `dtach` installed on all the boxes I wanted to use this on so I ended up using `screen` like so:

```
run("screen -d -m bash -c '{}'".format(command), pty=False)
```

This tells screen to start a bash shell in a detached terminal that runs your command

Answer (score 1):

You could be running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379484/fabric-appears-to-start-apache2-but-doesnt/)

Try adding 'pty=False' to the sudo command (I assume virtualenv is calling sudo or run somewhere?)

Comment: yeah still it hangs even with pty=False

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo('python %s/manage.py celerycam --detach --pidfile=celerycam.pid' % siteDir)
```

Edit: I had to make sure the pid file was removed first so this was the full code:

```
# Create new celerycam
sudo('rm celerycam.pid', warn_only=True)
sudo('python %s/manage.py celerycam --detach --pidfile=celerycam.pid' % siteDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent this issue by running `nohup ... &` over `ssh` in a separate local shell script.  In `fabfile.py`:

```
@task
def startup():
    local('./do-stuff-in-background.sh {0}'.format(env.host))
```

and in `do-stuff-in-background.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
set -o nounset

HOST=$1

ssh $HOST -T << HERE
   nohup df -h 1>>~/df.log 2>>~/df.err &
HERE
```

Of course, you could also pass in the command and standard output / error log files as arguments to make this script more generally useful.

(In my case, I didn't have admin rights to install `dtach`, and neither `screen -d -m` nor `pty=False` / `sleep 1` worked properly for me.  YMMV, especially as I have no idea *why* this works...)