# Fabric is blocking command with pty=False

Tags: python, jboss, fabric

I'm trying to start a remote service with fabric and as pointed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379484/fabric-appears-to-start-apache2-but-doesnt) my command is:

```
sudo('service jboss start', pty=False)
```

but unfortunately this command hangs on my terminal and I'm not able to close the fabric command, even with CTRL+C.

The only way I could find to workarround this issue is with a timeout option but if I have more tasks after that they don't run because the timeout is raised and the fab process is exited with an error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This might be the wrong track, but when I've had fabric hang on me, it  turned out the remote command was prompting for something, or was running in debug mode (where it spawns a process in the foreground).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's most likely related to these two FAQ points:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang

Comment: link only answers are discouraged. It would be appreciable to add the answer in the post itself and use link as source of extra information. That way the answer is still useful even if the link goes dead.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I added `nohup` to the beginning of the command and it worked.

Comment: Your links are broken, please fix them.